# Connection refused from host into a linux container with Docker for Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I found a lot of material on this issue online, however I wasn't able to find a solution. Also majority of them are rather old (a few years) and things could have considerably changed meanwhile.

I have **Docker Desktop Community v 2.3.0.3** running on my **Windows machine** and a simple container with **Ubuntu** and a **Rails** app running on **localhost:5000** inside.

The container gets run using:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 rails:6.0.3 foreman start
```

I would like to connect to the Rails app from my Windows host machine via browser, but connection gets refused.

The server is up and running:

```
> docker exec 3c167e206f60 wget localhost:5000
--2020-06-06 08:21:26--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Port forwarding doesn't seem to work correctly (run from WSL, but similarly from Windows via Chrome):

```
> wget localhost:5000
--2020-06-06 10:22:50--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... failed: Connection refused.
```

It doesn't work when using container address instead of localhost, either:

```
> docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 3c167e206f60
172.17.0.2
> wget 172.17.0.2:5000
--2020-06-06 10:29:02--  http://172.17.0.2:5000/
Connecting to 172.17.0.2:5000... failed: Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

Also (as probably expected), I don't see any docker related entry in **ifconfig** (from WSL) or **ipconfig** (from Windows) output.

I also tried `docker run --net host` parameter, which didn't help either.

I would ideally prefer a solution which doesn't require me to modify the Windows host setup (network setup, etc), to avoid the possibility of breaking other scenarios.

Comment: for port-forwarding, you need to expose the remote debug ports. PS: I think `5000` is port to access application

Comment: https://rollout.io/blog/running-rails-development-environment-docker/

Comment: The only difference between my setup and that in the article is that I didn't set up docker machine (I even tried to replace foreman with rails server). I don't think docker machine should be necessary, or am I wrong? Based on research on Internet I think the issue is with connecting from Windows host to Linux containers. Btw, where does the port 32769 come from in the article? Thx

Comment: `32769 ` this port is default port of application, i think and that is forwarded to  `3000` `0.0.0.0:32769->3000/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for several days. What worked for me was to:

1. Uninstall Docker Desktop
2. Turn off the Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, and Windows Hypervisor Platform via the Turn Windows Features On and Off control panel module
3. Reboot
4. Turn on all features in #2
5. Re-install Docker Desktop

This seems to reset all of the HyperV virtual networking interfaces. It's possible that uninstalling Docker Desktop isn't necessary but since it relies on at least some of these features I felt it wisest to do a complete cycle.